# Unknown enum type when modding Minecraft recipes with CraftTweaker

Tags: java, scripting, minecraft-modding

I want to make some new Recipes with CraftTweaker, which uses machines from the Create mod (I'm using Life In The Village 3), but I have the following error in my scripts:

[image: Error message screenshot]

```
[ERROR]: Error while running scripts:
org.openzen.zenscript.lexer.ParseException: CreateLapisDiamond.zs:16:57: Unknown enum type <constant:create:heat_condition:"heated">
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.api.bracket.custom.EnumConstantBracketHandler.lambda$parse$1(EnumConstantBracketHandler.java:53)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.api.bracket.custom.EnumConstantBracketHandler.parse(EnumConstantBracketHandler.java:53)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.scriptrun.runner.IgnorePrefixCasingBracketParser.parse(IgnorePrefixCasingBracketParser.java:37)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readPrimaryExpression(ParsedExpression.java:562)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readPostfixExpression(ParsedExpression.java:364)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readUnaryExpression(ParsedExpression.java:359)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readMulExpression(ParsedExpression.java:288)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAddExpression(ParsedExpression.java:258)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readShiftExpression(ParsedExpression.java:237)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readCompareExpression(ParsedExpression.java:166)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAndExpression(ParsedExpression.java:156)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readXorExpression(ParsedExpression.java:146)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readOrExpression(ParsedExpression.java:136)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAndAndExpression(ParsedExpression.java:126)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readOrOrExpression(ParsedExpression.java:110)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readConditionalExpression(ParsedExpression.java:97)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAssignExpression(ParsedExpression.java:49)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.parse(ParsedExpression.java:40)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedCallArguments.parse(ParsedCallArguments.java:46)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readPostfixExpression(ParsedExpression.java:399)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readUnaryExpression(ParsedExpression.java:359)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readMulExpression(ParsedExpression.java:288)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAddExpression(ParsedExpression.java:258)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readShiftExpression(ParsedExpression.java:237)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readCompareExpression(ParsedExpression.java:166)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAndExpression(ParsedExpression.java:156)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readXorExpression(ParsedExpression.java:146)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readOrExpression(ParsedExpression.java:136)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAndAndExpression(ParsedExpression.java:126)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readOrOrExpression(ParsedExpression.java:110)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readConditionalExpression(ParsedExpression.java:97)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.readAssignExpression(ParsedExpression.java:49)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.expression.ParsedExpression.parse(ParsedExpression.java:40)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.statements.ParsedStatement.parse(ParsedStatement.java:299)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.statements.ParsedStatement.parse(ParsedStatement.java:81)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.ParsedFile.parse(ParsedFile.java:215)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zenscript.parser.ParsedFile.parse(ParsedFile.java:158)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/org.openzen.zencode.java.ScriptingEngine.createScriptedModule(ScriptingEngine.java:123)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.scriptrun.runner.ScriptRunner.runScripts(ScriptRunner.java:86)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.scriptrun.runner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:69)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.scriptrun.DecoratedRunKind$DecoratedScriptRunner.run(DecoratedRunKind.java:27)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.scriptrun.ScriptRun.executeRun(ScriptRun.java:88)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.scriptrun.ScriptRun.execute(ScriptRun.java:54)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.ScriptReloadListener.apply(ScriptReloadListener.java:78)
at TRANSFORMER/crafttweaker@9.1.207/com.blamejared.crafttweaker.impl.script.ScriptReloadListener.m_5787_(ScriptReloadListener.java:37)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.packs.resources.SimplePreparableReloadListener.m_10789_(SimplePreparableReloadListener.java:13)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:718)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.packs.resources.SimpleReloadInstance.m_143940_(SimpleReloadInstance.java:69)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.m_6367_(BlockableEventLoop.java:198)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.m_6367_(ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.java:23)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.m_7245_(BlockableEventLoop.java:163)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.m_18701_(BlockableEventLoop.java:176)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.m_205125_(Minecraft.java:2082)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.doLoadLevel(Minecraft.java:1909)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.m_91200_(Minecraft.java:1873)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.worldselection.WorldSelectionList$WorldListEntry.m_101744_(WorldSelectionList.java:473)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.worldselection.WorldSelectionList$WorldListEntry.m_101704_(WorldSelectionList.java:330)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.worldselection.WorldSelectionList$WorldListEntry.m_6375_(WorldSelectionList.java:257)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.gui.components.AbstractSelectionList.m_6375_(AbstractSelectionList.java:323)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.gui.components.events.ContainerEventHandler.m_6375_(ContainerEventHandler.java:27)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.MouseHandler.m_168084_(MouseHandler.java:88)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.gui.screens.Screen.m_96579_(Screen.java:528)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.MouseHandler.m_91530_(MouseHandler.java:85)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.MouseHandler.m_168091_(MouseHandler.java:185)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.execute(BlockableEventLoop.java:118)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.MouseHandler.m_91565_(MouseHandler.java:184)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl.glfw/org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/org.lwjgl.glfw/org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWaitEventsTimeout(GLFW.java:3174)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.m_69830_(RenderSystem.java:225)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.m_91383_(Minecraft.java:1071)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.m_91374_(Minecraft.java:665)
at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:205)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/fmlloader@1.18.2-40.2.0/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.targets.CommonClientLaunchHandler.lambda$launchService$0(CommonClientLaunchHandler.java:31)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:53)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:71)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:106)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:77)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:26)
at MC-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@9.1.3/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapLaunchConsumer.accept(BootstrapLaunchConsumer.java:23)
at cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher@1.0.0/cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher.main(BootstrapLauncher.java:149)
[ERROR]: Scripts are invalid!
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
import crafttweaker.api.item.IItemStack;
import crafttweaker.api.ingredient.IIngredient;
import crafttweaker.api.recipe.FurnaceRecipeManager;

import mods.create.IProcessingRecipeManager;
import mods.create.MechanicalCrafterManager;
import mods.create.CrushingManager;
import mods.create.SplashingManager;
import mods.create.CompactingManager;
import mods.create.FillingManager;
import mods.create.MixingManager;
import mods.create.PressingManager;



<recipetype:create:compacting>.addRecipe("compact_coal", <constant:create:heat_condition:"heated">, [<item:minecraft:coal>], [<item:minecraft:charcoal>], 100);

<recipetype:create:crushing>.addRecipe("crush_lapis", [<item:minecraft:lapis_lazuli> * 2, <item:minecraft:lapis_lazuli> % 50], <item:create:asurine>, 100);
<recipetype:create:crushing>.addRecipe("crush_dia", [<item:minecraft:diamond> % 1], <item:minecraft:coal_block>, 400);
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown enum type" means the game doesn't recognize `<constant:create:heat_condition:"heated">` as being a valid label for a state.

So, [let's search for that key phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=constant%3Acreate%3Aheat_condition) `constant:create:heat_condition` to find out what *are* valid enum values we can use to describe heat conditions.

When I do this, the first result is [HeatCondition - CraftTweaker Documentation](https://docs.blamejared.com/1.18/it/mods/createtweaker/recipe/HeatCondition), which says the available values are:

```
<constant:create:heat_condition:none>
<constant:create:heat_condition:heated>
<constant:create:heat_condition:superheated>
```

Note that there are no quotation marks around `heated`, but in your script, there are. That means you should delete the quotation marks around `heated` in your script, so it matches one of the values above exactly.

Comment: I've tried the script without the quotation marks around `heated`  and it's still telling me the same error.